# Getting some already answered questions under "Unanswered" category

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I just went to page : https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered

Ex : [Loading page generates exception 'Timed out waiting for page load'](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9886/loading-page-generates-exception-timed-out-waiting-for-page-load)  - This question have many answers given but still it is coming under 
"Unanswered" category.

And found many questions which have lot of answers. Is this issue in https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ ?

I think those questions should be removed from "Unasnwered" category which have at least one answer.

Answer (score 6):

Got the thing like :

Hover over the "Unanswered" tab, and it tells - it's only going to show questions with no upvoted answers. So it will show questions which have no answers or many answers with no upvote on any answer.